# Any R package to calculate "Mutation Rates"

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have a large family data (Parents and children). All of them are in the form of alleles. i.e two alleles at each locus and subject. Our problem is to calculate mutation rate/counts (mismatches between child's alleles and parent's alleles) at each locus. Is there any R package which can easily do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: biostars.org is probably a better place to ask.  Biostars is about bioinformatics generally; SO is about programming problems.  (this isn't a programming question, it's asking for pre-made tools.)

Comment: So you are looking for de Novo mutations. What format is your data in? There are many analysis packages that might be able to do this if you tell us more about your data